# Does this citation style have a name?

Tags: citations, citation-style, reference-managers

I was asked to turn a set of references into the following citation format:

> [Qin2014] Z. Qin, G. Denker, C. Giannelli, P. Bellavista and N.
> Venkatasubramanian, “A software defined networking architecture for
> the internet-of-things,” 2014 IEEE network operations and management
> symposium (NOMS), 2014, pp. 1-9, doi: 10.1109/NOMS.2014.6838365

However, no information was given as to what the name of this style is.

Already tried looking in this website: https://editor.citationstyles.org/searchByExample/, but with no success.

Does anyone know if this style has a specific name?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3):

That looks to me like a `bibtex` style, probably `alpha`. So it's not a formal style (e.g. APA, MLA), it's just a setting for the `bibtex` package. Overleaf has a [full list of the styles](https://www.overleaf.com/learn/latex/bibtex_bibliography_styles).

Comment: alpha uses the authors' initials and a two digit year as the label, not the first authors name and a four digit year.

Answer (score 1):

Could be the [alphadin](https://www.bibtex.com/s/bibliography-style-din1505-alphadin/) style, which uses the old DIN 1505

Comment: According to the link you provided, should it be [QDGBV14] **...**?